# Unable to access ssl certificate from octopus library as X509Certificate2 object using powershell

Tags: powershell, ssl, ssl-certificate, octopus-deploy, octopus

I am trying to create a jwt token using a pfx which,I have stored in Octopus library. For this I have to create an object of X509Certificate2, which takes certificate path and password as input. Can someone please suggest a way to do this using powershell?

```
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($certpath,'password')
```

I have been through some documents as per how to access certificate variables in octopus but how can I use them to create an object of X509Certificate2.
https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/variables/certificate-variables

Answer (score 1):

After going through Microsoft and Octopus documentation I have managed to get it to work. Octopus store the certificate as a base64 encoded string in a variable named as Cert.Pfx and constructor of X509Certificate2 takes a byte array as a first parameter. So as a first step I just needed to convert the base64 encoded string to byte array.

```
$certbytearray=[System.Convert]::FromBase64String($OctopusParameters["Cert.Pfx"])
$CertPassKey="password"
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($certbytearray,$CertPassKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Biplab Thanks for posting your solution; it saved me a lot of headache! I had a slightly different situation without a password and I found that the X509Certificate2 constructor interpreted the byte array as a file name when I tried to call without the password even though the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1) indicates it should accept just a byte array.

I got it to work without the password by doing an import instead.

```
$certbytearray=[System.Convert]::FromBase64String($OctopusParameters["mycert.Pfx"])
$mycert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$mycert.import($certbytearray)
write-host $mycert.ThumbPrint
if ($mycert.HasPrivateKey)
{ write-host "has private key"}
```